# maven error "Fatal error compiling invalid flag: --release"

Tags: java, maven, soap, axis

I should made a wrapper that receive soap request in old format xmlrpc and convert to rest request and, cpnvert rest response to soap response. I have found this example on github

https://github.com/mpuening/learn-webservices-jaxrpc/tree/master

but when I try to compile it (after setting parent pom java version to 1.8 instead of 17) in the following way

<java.version>1.8</java.version>

I'll get maven error "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project learn-webservices-jaxrpc-legacy-axis: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release" .

running mvn -version on prompt I'll get the following result

```
Maven home: C:\Users\Utente\Documents\apache-maven-3.8.6
Java version: 1.8.0_381, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\jre
Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

JAVA_HOME user variable and system variable environment point to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8, in eclipse is setted as default jdk the same jdk in JAVA_HOME.

How can I solve this issue ? I have already searched on the web but I don't have found an explanation.

Even if the default java version is 17 the syntax is compatble with java 1.8, except for axis (for this reason author has written

"The only trouble I had is that Axis doesn't quite understand Java 8 syntax, so just keep Java 8 syntax out of the Axis Service class and you should be fine. This is why there is both an AxisAircraftService and an AircraftService class.")

Hope that somebody help me

Best regards

I have tried to compile but it doesn't compile. Actually it's showed an error

Comment: Spring boot 3.1.x require Java 17.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.system-requirements

Comment: First you are using JDK 8 which will not work with Spring Boot 3.X because it requires JDK17+ as already mentioned... You can only use Spring Boot 2.7.X version  which requires JDK 8 as minimum...

Comment: ok, thank You for the answer, I have change git brach to jakarta 8 and automatically is set "Spring Boot 2.7.5" in the parent pom... but now I have another problem: if I try to import wsdl in soapui and send request I'll get error 401 ... why? the wsdl should be the same, it isn't changed. Finally I have another request: if I want convert from war to jar standalone what should I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

--release flag is supported only since Java 1.9, you might be using <1.0 JDK in your machine.